# Vuejs MPA and indexPath per page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, multi-page-application

in `vue.config.js` - one can set the output location and file name of the `index.html` using `indexPath`

e.g. `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    indexPath: "../backend/api/templates/base.html"
}
```

will output the `index.html` file to `backend/api/templates` named `"base.html"`.

I want to build an MPA where several htmls are generated.

via:

```
module.exports = {
    pages: {
        index: {
            entry: "./src/pages/home/main.ts",
            template: "public/index.html",
            filename: "index.html",
            chunks: ["chunk-vendors", "index"]
        },
        about: {
            entry: "./src/pages/about/main.ts",
            template: "public/index.html",
            filename: "about.html",
            chunks: ["chunk-vendors", "about"]
        }
    },

    outputDir: "backend/api/static/dist",
    assetsDir: "static",
    indexPath: "../backend/api/templates/base-vue.html",
...
```

However I can only get `index.html` to be renamed to `base-vue.html`.

**I want to be able to have `about.html` output into a specific folder with a specific name.**
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

For posterity - thanks to wrksx on Vue Land discord:

The `filename` field can include a path relative to the `outputDir`

```js
module.exports = {
    pages: {
        index: {
            entry: "./src/pages/home/main.ts",
            template: "public/index.html",
            filename: "../../templates/base-vue.html",
            chunks: ["chunk-vendors", "index"]
        },
        about: {
            entry: "./src/pages/about/main.ts",
            template: "public/index.html",
            filename: "../../templates/base-vue-about.html",
            chunks: ["chunk-vendors", "about"]
        }
    },

    outputDir: "backend/api/static/dist",
// not needed   assetsDir: "static",
// not needed   indexPath: "../backend/api/templates/base-vue.html",
```

outputs:

```
backend
|---api
    |---static
    |   |--- dist
    |   |      payload of js, css, img etc
    |---templates
        |--- base-vue.html
        |--- base-vue-about.html
```

Comment: I spent several hours to achieve it, this posts resolves my goal. Thank you